# How to get min value of specific column from belongsToMany relationship in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relationship between **projects-devices tables**. And I want to **get min value of a specific column (battery level)** from **devices table** for each project.

I can success this with only one sql command. But how can I do that with an effective eloquent? Thank you.

1st table: projects
-- id
-- name
-- .
-- .
-- .
2nd table: devices
-- id
-- battery_level
-- .
-- .
-- .
3rd pivot table: device_project
-- device_id
-- project_id

Tables link is [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9104418/88290962-328cbe00-cd00-11ea-8ee1-f49b6c6678c7.PNG)
Query result which I wanna get is [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9104418/88290960-315b9100-cd00-11ea-8d87-8223b8c898fc.PNG)

### With raw sql:

This works well as I want, but I wanna do  this with eloquent.

```
$projects = DB::select( DB::raw("select
`projects`.`id`, `projects`.`name`,
(select
    `battery_level`
    from `devices`
    inner join `device_project`
    on `devices`.`id` = `device_project`.`device_id`
    where `projects`.`id` = `device_project`.`project_id`
    order by `battery_level`
    limit 1
) as `lowest_battery_level`
from `projects`"));

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $values[] = $project->lowest_battery_level
}
```

### **With eloquent:**

The problem on this: it will send two separate sql queries although I can do that with only 1 query by using raw sql. Also it gets all devices' battery levels from database. But I need only the lowest one for each project.

```
$projects = Project::with('devices:battery_level')->get();

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $values[] = $project->devices->min('battery_level')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer after many try. Hope this can help others as well.

**addSelect** method helped me about this and my eloquent code is more effective now. This creates only one query and no detailed (unnecessary) information about devices as I wanted. It gives only the lowest battery level for each projects.

### Eloquent code for this:

```
$projects = Project::select('projects.id', 'projects.name')
    ->addSelect([
        'lowest_battery_level' => Device::select('battery_level')
        ->leftJoin('device_project', 'device_project.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
        ->whereColumn('device_project.project_id', 'projects.id')
        ->orderBy('battery_level', 'asc') // no need asc if you wanna get lowest value first
        ->limit(1)
    ])
->get();

// can use like this
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $values[] = $project->lowest_battery_level
}
```

### This creates sql query like this:

Creates only 1 query and get only projects results without other devices' details.

```
select
    `projects`.`id`, 
    `projects`.`name`,
    (
        select
            `battery_level`
        from `devices`
        inner join `device_project` on `devices`.`id` = `device_project`.`device_id`
        where `projects`.`id` = `device_project`.`project_id`
        order by `battery_level`
        limit 1
    ) as `lowest_battery_level`
from `projects`
```

### Performance Comparison with Laravel Debugbar

There are **100 projects** and **1000 devices** in database. And every project have relationship **randomly with 0-50 of devices**. Also different projects can have relationship with same devices (many-to-many relationship).

**With previous eloquent code:**

```
$projects = Project::with('devices:battery_level')->get();

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $values[] = $project->devices->min('battery_level')
}
```

> As it can be seen below, it uses **18 MB RAM** and **took 539 ms**.
> Creates **2783 Device objects** and **100 Project objects**

[image: a busy cat]

**With new eloquent code:** (which I showed above)

> As it can be seen below, it uses **10 MB RAM** and **took 432 ms**.
> Creates **no Device objects** and **only 100 Project objects**

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

in your **project** model define the relationship like this

```
public function devices()
{
return $this->belongToMany(Device::class);
}
```

and in your **device** model define the relationship like this

```
public function projects()
{
return $this->belongToMany(Project::class);
}
```

then get the projects in yur controller

```
$values = [];
$project = Project::find(1); //write your own custom code for gettign the projects
foreach($project->devices as $device)
$values[] = $device->battery_level;

dd($values);
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesnt improve my method as well. additionally you get all columns from projects and devices tables even if I dont need all. I dont wanna get all battery level informations as well. I just need the lowest one.

Comment: then what is ou lowest battery level

Comment: I have projects table and devices table. These tables have many-to-many relationship so I have pivot table named as device_project.In my query result I wanna get every project name and lowest battery levels of devices which is related to each project. My tables structures: [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9104418/88290962-328cbe00-cd00-11ea-8ee1-f49b6c6678c7.PNG), Result which I wanna get: [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9104418/88290960-315b9100-cd00-11ea-8d87-8223b8c898fc.PNG). Also I want this query to be efficient as I showed as raw sql in my question.

Comment: are you sure you need a pivot result for getting this result? Because I think one to many is better approach for getting this result. Think about it

Comment: yes because each device can have many projects and each project can have many devices. So it should be many-to-many relationship

Comment: ok then let's see other can help you r not. But according to your result i think you need 1 to M

Comment: okay thank you for your interest. But in my project requirement is that a device can be related to many projects and a project can be related to many devices too. So I needed a pivot table. Actually I wanna learn how I can get lowest value of belongsToMany relationship in eloquent. Also I can do this in raw sql. Just need to convert to eloquent.

Comment: $project->devices->min('battery_level') you ca use these or if you want in assending order the in your model you can use it like these return $this->belongToMany(Device::class)->orderBy('battery_level','asc');  thats teh all i can help you

Comment: okay thanks, I did like this already in my question too. I just wanted to improve my eloquent structure. Because when I do like this, it sends 2 separate queries to database. I just thought I dont need to send second queries. My question is about improving eloquent structure. But thanks for help